# Windows 10 64-bit: ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0), here is why:

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, ssl-certificate, compass-sass

I'm trying to install ruby in windows 10. For install compass & SASS but I'm unable to install this I tried all the things I know it & as per various question answer from various website including stack overflow.

```
set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem
```

or

```
set SSL_CERT_FILE= curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

gem install compass
```

Received Following Error Message:

> ```
> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0), here is why:
>       Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:
> ```
>
> certificate verify failed

[Image with error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0OT2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this file `cacert.pem` somewhere in your Ruby folder

and then create environmental variable and give the path of this file such as

[image]

Then it will work.

Comment: I create new environmental variable & with you provided information but getting same error and also change the cacert.pem file path in ruby23 folder outside bin folder

Comment: Outside the bin folder or inside the bin folder doesn't matter at all, you set that path in environmental variable as shown above.

Comment: Yes I set the path just inside Ruby23 but getting same error not able to install compass

Comment: Did you put the file in Ruby23? Cacert.pem file is inside Ruby23?

Comment: Yes I set the Environmental variable of cacert.pem and also put file in Ruby23 folder

Comment: Can you please give your email id, I will send you cacert.pem, You can replace with mine and check whether it works or not?

Comment: shankal10@gmail.com

Comment: Please check the mail and let me know whether it works.

Comment: It din't work for me. However placing it with the other .pem files inside Ruby and modifying the same in Environmental Variables worked for me.

Comment: @Siva-Dev-Wizard Install Ruby 2.3.3 this arrangement is not necessary