# How to fix (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed) in Win7-64

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl

I recently begun work in Ruby with 'open-uri' and 'net/http' but when i try to run my program the console show me 'OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed'; i just upgrade the new GlobalSignRootCA.pem and putting in 'ssl_cert' folder(http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/#manual-solution-to-ssl-issue), that allow me to install and upgrade gems without problem, but when i run some program who require 'open-uri' or 'net/http' error appears again. I'm working in Win7-64 but there is very difficult to find some approach.
Do you know how to fix this, is drives me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found is:

```
# remove https source:
gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/

# add http source:
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org

# update 'rubygems':
gem update --system

# now return to https:
gem sources -r http://rubygems.org/
gem sources -a https://rubygems.org/
```

I know it's not perfect but it solves the problem.

Comment: Does running `gem install bundler` first maybe help?  The guides mention how to fix SSL errors here: http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution to the exact problem you have been facing, but I have the problem while I try to install the gem, I included `cacert.pem` consequently it works fine. Can you check my answer here and do the following and that might resolve your problem.

[Windows 10 64-bit: ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0), here is why:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285447/windows-10-64-bit-error-could-not-find-a-valid-gem-compass-0-here-is-w/40285571#40285571)

I know I am not giving the exact solution to your problem, but please give a try, let's see what happen.